How to add new tablerow on each button click
I am using Flutter. I have a string list.
I need to add a new row after clicking a button.
I need to track the number of times I clicked the button to add the correct number of rows.
The following code is not working - I don't see the new table row added.
Another issue is that I get error after clicking addRow button:

RangeError (length): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1

Code:
List<String?> = myData[''];

static List<DataRow?> myTableRowsList=[DataRow(cells: <DataCell>[DataCell(Text('-'))])];

int i = 0;

addRow(){
    setState(() {
      i = i + 1;
      myTableRowsList.add(DataRow(cells: <DataCell>[DataCell(Text(myData[i]!)))
      ]));
  });
  }

Widget mybutton = TextButton(onPressed: addRow);

Widget mytable = Container(child: SizedBox(height: 1000, child:DataTable(columns: [
          DataColumn(label: Text('myTestData'))],
                rows: List<DataRow>.generate(myData.length,(i) => DataRow(cells: [
          DataCell(DropdownButton<String>(value: myData[i],onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                 setState(() {
                   myData[i] = newValue!;
                 });
               },
                   items: myData.map((xyz) {
                     return DropdownMenuItem<String>(value: xyz,child: Text(xyz!));
                   }).toList()))
                ]))
        )));


To add dynamically row to a table in flutter, you can follow the pattern in the code below:
class CustomTable extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomTable({super.key});

  @override
  State<CustomTable> createState() => _CustomTableState();
}

class _CustomTableState extends State<CustomTable> {
  var rowsData = ['row 1', 'row 2', 'row 3', 'row 4'];
  var rows = <DataRow>[];
  var rowIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        DataTable(
          columns: const [DataColumn(label: Text('myTestData'))],
          rows: rows,
        ),
        TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                if (rowIndex < rowsData.length) {
                  rows.add(DataRow(cells: [DataCell(Text(rowsData[rowIndex]))]));
                  rowIndex++;
                }
              });
            },
            child: Text('Add Row')),
      ],
    );
  }
}


By using rowIndex < rowsData.length, we make sure to just add as many rows as we have in rowsData
rows variable is responsible to shows the rows in our table and we add one more DataRow every time the user click on the button.
setState will rebuild the widget and the DataTable widget will render our new rows varibale which contains new DataRow.

If there is any ambiguity feel free to leave a comment and I would be happy to respond.
